# Do I need to initialize a list with new in c#?

Tags: c#

I have the following class:

```
public class CityDetailViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<City.Grid> Detail { get; set; }
    public SelectList Statuses { get; set; }
    public string Topics { get; set; }
    public SelectList Types { get; set; }
}
```

In my code I have:

```
    public ActionResult getGrid(string pk, string rk) {
        var ms = new List<long>();
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var vm = new CityDetailViewModel();
```

I want to put the variable ms into my CityDetailViewModel class.

```
public class CityDetailViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<City.Grid> Detail { get; set; }
    public SelectList Statuses { get; set; }
    public string Topics { get; set; }
    public SelectList Types { get; set; }
    public List<long> MS { get; set; }
}
```

Is this the correct way to do it. I'm not sure but do I need to use "new". Also in my code I add to the list using:

```
ms.Add(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

If it is part of the CityDetailViewModel can  I still do that using:

```
MS.Add(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

Comment: Your example (and code) could benefit from some more verbose variable names for readability

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you create a new instance of `CityDetailViewModel`, the member `MS` will be `null`, hence 
calling `Add` on it will raise a `NullReferenceException`.

You can either create a new `List<long>` inside the class' constructor, or create a new one outside of it

```
public class CityDetailViewModel
{
     ...

     public CityDetailViewModel()
     {
         this.MS = new List<long>();
     }
}

public ActionResult getGrid(string pk, string rk) {
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var vm = new CityDetailViewModel();
    ...
    vm.MS.Add(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

or

```
public ActionResult getGrid(string pk, string rk) {
    var ms = new List<long>();
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var vm = new CityDetailViewModel() { MS = ms };
    ...
    ms.Add(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

since `ms` and `vm.MS` will be the same list instance here.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you need to initialize your list -- using these auto properties I'd suggest doing this within the constructor. This way you can make the `set`-ter of the list `private` because no one should be able to reinitialize the list from the outside of your class.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't initialize the list, it will be `null`, and trying to call `Add` on it will result in a `NullReferenceException`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can access the MS property that way.

The thing you need to watch out for is the initialization of the MS List. So in the list initialization to the models constructor. Otherwise you will get NullReferenceExceptions.

I assume that you are populating the Detail and other SelectLists with your datasource data and not accessing them straight without initialization either.

```
public class CityDetailViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<City.Grid> Detail { get; set; }
    public SelectList Statuses { get; set; }
    public string Topics { get; set; }
    public SelectList Types { get; set; }
    public List<long> MS { get; set; }

    public CityDetailViewModel() 
    {
        MS = new List<long>();
    }
}
```

The reason you have to do this in the constructor is that you are using auto properties. If you use a backing property instead, then you can initialize the property outside the constructor.

Like so

```
public class CityDetailViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<City.Grid> Detail { get; set; }
    public SelectList Statuses { get; set; }
    public string Topics { get; set; }
    public SelectList Types { get; set; }
    private List<long> _ms = new List<long>();
    public List<long> MS { 
        get { return _ms; }
        set { _ms = value; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to extend CityDetailViewModel with a ctor like this:

```
public class CityDetailViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<City.Grid> Detail { get; set; }
    public SelectList Statuses { get; set; }
    public string Topics { get; set; }
    public SelectList Types { get; set; }
    public List<long> MS { get; set; }

    public CityDetailViewModel (){
        MS = new List<long>();
    }
}
```

Then you can do

```
public ActionResult getGrid(string pk, string rk) {
    var vm = new CityDetailViewModel();
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    vm.MS.Add(sw);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The initialization within the getGrid method could be achieved through by passing the ms variable into the CityDetailViewModel

```
public ActionResult getGrid(string pk, string rk) {
    var ms = new List<long>();
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var vm = new CityDetailViewModel { MS = ms };
```

ms does need to instantiated before being passed in other wise a call to `vm.MS.Add(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds)` will result in a `NullReferenceException`.